# Unit Testing How to access object property

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a simple angular service:

```
app.service('myService', function() {

    this.getMsg = function (status, data) {

        var errMsg = '';

        if (status.toString()[0] == 4) {

            if ((data.message.indexOf("3 tries left") > -1) || (data.message.indexOf("2 tries left")) > -1){
                errMsg = "Opps, try later";
            }
            else {
                errMsg = "Please try again.";
            }
        }

        if (status.toString()[0] == 5) {
            errMsg = "Under Construction";
        }

        return errMsg;
    };
});
```

And I have wrote a test that ensures my `getMsg` function exists, however when I try to test the function, I get an error:

> TypeError: data.message is undefined

Test:

```
describe('myService', function (){
  var myService;

  beforeEach(function (){

    module('myApp');

    inject(function(_myService_) {
      myService = _myService_;
    });
  });

  it('should have an getMsg function', function () { 
    expect(angular.isFunction(myService.getMsg)).toBe(true);
  });

  it('test fucntion', function (){
    var result = myService.getMsg(400, "some text to test");
    expect(result).toBe('bar!!!');
  });
});
```

Comment: Why has this been down voted? I have explained the issue, and provided code. Sufficient code is there for an answer to be proved within a couple of minutes as @Tibos has highlighted below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between the way you expected the `getMsg` function to behave when you wrote the function and the way you expected it to behave when you tested it.

When you wrote it, you expected the second parameter to be an object which has a `message` property which is a string.

When you tested it, you expected the second parameter to be a string.

If your function is correct, you should change this line

```
var result = myService.getMsg(400, "some text to test");
```

to

```
var result = myService.getMsg(400, { message : "some text to test"});
```